# How to apply R function Assocstats of library VCD in Rpy python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to calculate statistical parameters phi coefficient, Cramer's V and Contigency Coefficient using Rpy module of python. In R I am able to do so but I am at my wits end in my attempts to replicate the same in python

```
Library(vcd)
data <- read.csv("test.csv")
assocstats(table(data$var_4, data$target)

Output     
                X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 113.28  1        0
Pearson          112.51  1        0

Phi-Coefficient   : 0.15 
Contingency Coeff.: 0.148 
Cramer's V        : 0.15
```

Implementation in python

```
from Rpy import r
# Already connected with mysql
q="Select var_4 , target from test"
cur.execute(q)
data=cur.fetchall()
ls1=[]
ls2=[]
for i in range(len(data)):
  ls1.append(data[i][0])
  ls2.append(data[i][1])
rpy.r.library("vcd")
rpy.r.assocstats(rpy.r.table(ls1,ls2))
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
rpy.r.assocstats(rpy.r.table(ls1,ls2))
RPy_RException: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

The other way I am trying is to calculate the phi sq from scipy module and then use the mathematical formula to calculate cramer's v etc. But I intend to use Rpy heavily in my project going forward.I would really appreciate I you can point out the problem in above approach . I think I am not able to pass on the input in proper format in the formula
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error we can see that `sort` function has issues with `list` input. Testing this case for a sample list

```
templist<-list(c(3,2,1))
> sort(templist)
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic

newlist<-unlist(templist)
>is.atomic(newlist)
[1] TRUE

> sort(newlist)
[1] 1 2 3
```

The key here is `unlist`, You can confirm if your inputs `ls1` and `ls2` are `list`(s) using, `rpy.r.is.list`. To unlist them, `rpy.r.unlist` needs to be called on both `ls1` and `ls2`.

To be able use functions with `.` in the function name such as `is.list()`, you could refer to ([Accessing functions with a dot in theior name (eg. "as.vector") using rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032060/accessing-functions-with-a-dot-in-theior-name-eg-as-vector-using-rpy2))

I do not have rpy hence cannot confirm but I suppose this should work, let us know.

Comment: Thanks a lot .  Now I am facing a new error. I am working on it to resolve. I will let you know how it go .                       Error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    r.assocstats(r.table(newls1,newls2))
RPy_RException: Error in function (x)  : Function only defined for 2-way tables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using `rpy2` as you stated in the tags? Looks to be `rpy` to me. Anyway, I strongly recommend you to migrate to `rpy2` if you haven't done so.

Looks like your `ls1` `ls2` are just lists of numbers, the problem should be a very simple one:

```
In [60]:
#setting up
import rpy2.robjects as ro
mydata = ro.r['data.frame']
table = ro.r['table']
assocstats = ro.r['assocstats']
summary = ro.r['summary']
ro.r['library']('vcd')
ls1=np.random.random(50)
ls2=np.random.random(50)
result=assocstats(table(ls1, ls2))

In [61]:
#what is in the result
print result.names
[1] "table"       "chisq_tests" "phi"         "contingency" "cramer"     

In [62]:
#access the chi-sqaure table
print result.rx('chisq_tests')
$chisq_tests
                       X^2   df  P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio  391.2023 2401 1.0000000
Pearson          2450.0000 2401 0.2382456
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Let me install rpy2 and test. I will let you know in case if I face any trouble

Comment: Thanks a ton it worked. Only thing that I needed to change was unlisting the list I had in python.