# How to call an R function with a dot in its name by pyRserve?

Tags: python, r, rserve, pyrserve

pyRserve module is really handy when interacting with Rserve session from python.

You get access to an R object by prefix its name with expression like "conn.r" or "conn.ref"

```
import pyRserve
import numpy
conn = pyRserve.connect()
conn.r.List = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
conn.r.sapply(conn.ref.List, conn.ref.sqrt)
Out[23]: array([ 1.04880885,  1.4832397 ,  1.81659021])
```

But this won't work if there's a dot in the function name,

```
conn.r.sapply(conn.ref.List, conn.ref.as.integer)
    conn.r.sapply(conn.ref.List, conn.ref.as.integer)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the only solution I came up with is to wrap the whole R expression in a string and
run it using eval function:

```
conn.eval('result = as.integer(List)')
conn.r.result
Out[46]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Is there any more productive way of doing it?

Note: I realized in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032060/accessing-functions-with-a-dot-in-theior-name-eg-as-vector-using-rpy2) similar question has been asked an answered for rpy2 module (another python R binding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution which is inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python?rq=1):

```
as_integer = getattr(conn.r, 'as.integer')
conn.r.sapply(conn.ref.List, as_integer)
Out[8]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```