# Rpy2 - calling functions with a dot in their name

Tags: r, python-3.x, rpy2

I am trying to call the R function memory.limit, with the argument 'size', using rpy2. I followed the instructions given here: [Accessing functions with a dot in their name (eg. "as.vector") using rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032060/accessing-functions-with-a-dot-in-their-name-eg-as-vector-using-rpy2), but cannot get it to work.

This is what I have tried:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2 import robjects

utils = importr('utils')
memory_limit = robjects.r("memory.limit")
utils.memory_limit(size=50000)
```

and also

```
from rpy2 import robjects

memory_limit = robjects.r("memory.limit")
memory_limit(size=50000)
```

In both cases I get the following error:

```
RRuntimeError: Error in (function (size = NA)  : incorrect argument
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess by now you have solved this, but I would do like this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
memory_limit = robjects.r('utils::memory.limit')
memory_limit(size=50000)
```